# "aws ecs describe-clusters" doesn't return the cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

In the AWS Console, I created a cluster, task definition and repository for deploying my docker image. Then I created an IAM user and tried to list the clusters I have by calling

```
aws ecs describe-clusters
```

It returns me

```
{
    "clusters": [], 
    "failures": [
        {
            "reason": "MISSING", 
            "arn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:cluster/default"
        }
    ]
 }
```

Listing clusters also returns me empty array,

```
aws ecs list-clusters
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: tried running `aws ecs describe-clusters --cluster default` ?

Comment: Pass the region where you cluster is actually created by using  "aws ecs describe-clusters --region us-east-1"

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the cluster name is not default. Still, while trying it is returning the same failure result.

Comment: @ManishR I tried with the region as well. Still the same result.

I am suspecting an issue with IAM policies. Any idea?

Comment: It seems the issue with your region. Do pass the correct region with --region parameter.

Comment: If you type `aws configure --list` do you get the region and the account you expect?

Comment: @VishnuSankaran What do you see when you run `aws configure list | grep region`? This is how your `aws-cli` is configured. When you sign in to the AWS Management Console, what region name do you see in the top-right corner? This is _probably_ how your ECS cluster was configured. If they don't match, then you are probably querying the wrong AWS region when you run `aws ecs describe-clusters `. Read more here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ecs_region

Answer (score 4):

Execute

```
aws configure
```

Adjust "Default region name:" and execute again

```
aws ecs list-clusters
```

Comment: I think it would be useful to explain why you think `aws configure` and adjusting the default region would help solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a bit late and I hope it helps somebody.

First you need to list your clusters

```
$ aws ecs list-clusters
{
    "clusterArns": [
        "arn:aws:ecs:<aws_region>:<accn_id>:cluster/cumbancha-cluster"
    ]
}
```

Then, grab the cluster name from the previous output (in this case `cumbancha-cluster`) and try `describe-clusters` command again

```
$ aws ecs describe-clusters --cluster cumbancha-cluster
{
    "clusters": [
        {
            "clusterArn": "arn:aws:ecs:<aws_region>:<accn_id>:cluster/cumbancha-cluster",
            "clusterName": "cumbancha-cluster",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "registeredContainerInstancesCount": 1,
            "runningTasksCount": 3,
            "pendingTasksCount": 0,
            "activeServicesCount": 3,
            "statistics": [],
            "tags": [],
            "settings": [
                {
                    "name": "containerInsights",
                    "value": "disabled"
                }
            ],
            "capacityProviders": [],
            "defaultCapacityProviderStrategy": []
        }
    ],
    "failures": []
}
```

Comment: OP said he gets an empty array for `list-clusters`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well.
The solution:

- the `describe-clusters` command requires an input parameter `--cluster` in order to find the cluster in the way that you're calling it.

First, run `aws ecs list-clusters` to get your cluster(s) name.

Second, run `aws ecs describe-clusters --cluster [cluster-name]`

Provide the ecs cluster that you would like to describe in place of `cluster-name`.

(Assuming your region, profile, aws cli are configured correctly)

Answer (score 0):

The above error suggest that the script is not able to load your default profile. It is always a good practice to add your profile and region to the script. I am assuming here that you have already did the configuration by "aws configure" cli command. Below is the snippet:

```
aws ecs describe-clusters --profile <YOUR-PROFILE> --region <AWS-REGION>
```

You can find the profile in the /.aws/config file.

Answer (score 0):

One thing other answers missed is the fact that `describe-clusters` expects that cluster with name `default` exits if no cluster is specified. You can have as many clusters as you want but the error will show up if you don't specify the one you want to view.

As others pointed out you may need to specify correct region value (using `aws configure`, `--region` param, `AWS_REGION` env variable...). If you already did then perhaps resources were created in wrong region in aws web console?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
aws ecs describe-services --services <service_name> --cluster <cluster_name> --region <region_name>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @user2672498 - Try adding more details to help understand Vishnu, and BTW, this could have been a comment, instead of answer

Comment: Specifically, it'd be useful to [edit] your answer to explain why you prefer this over the existing answers. Does it take advantage of new capabilities? Are there problems with the previous answers that you're addressing? Are there circumstances where this will work better? How? That would be useful information to include when there are so many existing answers.